# Magnific Popup custom arrow and number

Tags: magnific-popup

i am making custom modal for my project. using Magnific Popup. but still can not find out how can i full custom  arrow and number. i really `http://pixelgrade.com/demos/lens/gallery/grid-gallery/` them style they also used Magnific Popup. them arrow and number side by side.

bellow is code i did but now how can i include arrow in **tCounter** or have any other way to make like ref. website.

```
gallery: {
  enabled: true, // set to true to enable gallery

  preload: [0,2], // read about this option in next Lazy-loading section

  navigateByImgClick: true,

  arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"></button>', // markup of an arrow button

  tPrev: 'Previous (Left arrow key)', // title for left button
  tNext: 'Next (Right arrow key)', // title for right button
  tCounter: '<span class="mfp-counter"><span>%curr%</span> of %total%</span>' // markup of counter
},
```